# Calling a Haskell function from Ruby on Heroku

Tags: ruby, haskell, heroku

So I'd like to call a Haskell function from a Ruby app running on Heroku.  I'm aware of [Hubris](https://github.com/mwotton/Hubris), but it seems unlikely to work in the Heroku sandbox, so I'm thinking of automatically converting the Haskell code to Ruby.  Unsurprisingly, there's no tool that will do this in one shot, but there appear to be a whole bunch of Haskell-to-X and Y-to-Ruby tools.  Which would do the trick, or are there other solutions I'm missing?

And yes, I'm aware that any twice-generated code would be horribly obfuscated code spaghetti, and I'm OK with that as long as it works.

Comment: Haskell and Ruby are so different that you're often best off just rewriting in a situation like this.

Comment: Are you aware of multi-buildpack? that would allow you to run both haskell and ruby in the same app, and you could shell out at the very least.

Comment: @Will: No, I was not, but that might be the ticket, and I could use eg. https://github.com/begriffs/heroku-buildpack-ghc to spin up the Haskell app in a separate dyno.  Please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use [multi-buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) to have an app that has both ruby and haskell. Multi-buildpack is a [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) that allows you to compose several buildpacks into one. With this you could use both the official Heroku ruby buildpack (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git) and a [3rd party](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/third-party-buildpacks) haskell buildpack.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby and Haskell are have very different evaluation models. Unless you have a *very* compelling case, you'd be better off trying a different integration path.

Here is a talk from Haskell Exchange 2012 that talks about integrating haskell and ruby via ampq. https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/3637-integrating-haskell-using-amqp